# can not load UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am new to objective C.
I am trying to load new view from current view on button click but when i click on button it executes a code but does nothing i.e. does not load new view controller..
following is my code...

```
- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)resultString {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

//Display QRCode in string....
NSLog(@"Result::::%@",resultString);

[_qrCodeParser initWithQRString:resultString];
int i=[_qrCodeParser parseQROCode];
sharedInstance=[SharedInstance sharedInstance];
NSLog(@"%@",sharedInstance._medicineData);
if (i==0) {
    _detailView= [[AlarmViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlarmViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:_detailView animated:YES completion:nil];
}

}
```

Comment: I have never seen objective C, where is your `button click handler`? Should you invoke some kind of `show` function on the initialized `_detailView`?

Comment: didScanResult is called automatically on button click as it is delegate method of ZXing SDK

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you're doing in this method? If you're dismissing the current VC, then the previous VC in the stack will be presented after dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with removing "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated" controller line like below:

```
- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)resultString {
//[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

//Display QRCode in string....
NSLog(@"Result::::%@",resultString);

[_qrCodeParser initWithQRString:resultString];
int i=[_qrCodeParser parseQROCode];
sharedInstance=[SharedInstance sharedInstance];
NSLog(@"%@",sharedInstance._medicineData);
if (i==0) 
{
    _detailView= [[AlarmViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlarmViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:_detailView animated:YES completion:nil];
}


}
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried with your suggestion. but this time it is showing a blank screen and even it is not going to viewDidLoad of AlarmViewController....

Comment: Not getting you exactly by means of "blank screen". It is "AlarmViewController". And try with "viewWillAppear" method of "AlarmViewController" class. It can be helpful to you as well.